# netplan: Is there a way to set the name of a wifi interface to an easier one?

Tags: wifi, netplan

Using netplan / networkd for wifi and I'd like to do the following

```
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlx1cbfceac3e27:
      match:
         macaddress: 01:d2:f3:c4:95:96
      set-name: wlan0
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.2/24
      access-points:
        "Linux is the best":
           password: "yobeach"
```

However, netplan interjects

```
networkd backend does not support wifi with match:, only by interface name
```

Since `set-name` requires a `match`, is there another way in the netplan syntax to change the name to wlan0 (not using `udev`)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, netplan doesn't accept a long interface name.

Write a `/etc/systemd/network/99-rename-wlx1cbfceac3e27.link` file with the following content:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=01:d2:f3:c4:95:96

[Link]
Name=wlan0
```

`Path=pci-****` accepted instead of `MACAddress`

Edit your netplan with the correct wifi interface name, then reboot.